# Biased results based on node type (Search API Solr)

Tags: 7, search

I want to create a weight bias for all of my node types.

Node Types:

- Articles
- Blog
- Content

The situation:

Right now Articles will be mixed in with Blog and Content. What I want is whenever there is an "Articles" node returned I want them to show first no matter what. Second would be Blog, third would be Content.

-

What I have done:

I have looked into possibly trying to bias using the QueryElevationComponent but that elevates based on the Solr Doc ID which I would have to manually set for each node. I have also looked into boosting based on the value of a field but this is numerical in nature I would somehow need to get a numerical value associated with every document that was a reflection of the Content Type's order. This doesn't seem like the best way to go.

-

References:

- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent
- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_change_the_score_of_a_document_based_on_the_.2Avalue.2A_of_a_field_.28say.2C_.22popularity.22.29

-

Results from hook_search_api_solr_search_results_alter

```
results (Array, 10 elements)
    15681 (Array, 3 elements)
        id (String, 5 characters ) 15681
        score (Float) 4.8259773
        fields (Array, 2 elements)
            search_api_id (String, 5 characters ) 15681
            search_api_relevance (Float) 4.8259773
```